# Why is my IPersistenceStore implementation not being respected?

Tags: glimpse

I am trying to create a new implementation of `IPersistenceStore`.

I understand I need to register my new implementation by using a `IServiceLocator` which is configured in the glimpse node of my `web.config` like so:

```
<glimpse defaultRuntimePolicy="On" endpointBaseUri="~/Glimpse.axd" serviceLocatorType="MyNewServiceLocator, MyAssembly">
```

However, I am seeing the following behaviour:

- The `GetInstance` method of my `IServiceLocator` is never hit
- The ctor of my new `IPersistenceStore` is hit at app start up
- No other methods on my `IPersistenceStore` are ever hit (ie the Glimpse data is still being stored in the default impl of `IPersistenceStore`)

It appears that my `IPersistenceStore` is not being registered correctly. Why could this be?

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear what could be wrong, as you don't show any of your code related to the `IServiceLocator`

Something along these lines should suffice to have your custom persistence store returned by your custom service locator:

```
public class MyNewServiceLocator : IServiceLocator
{
    public T GetInstance<T>() where T : class
    {
        var type = typeof(T);
        if (type == typeof(IPersistenceStore))
        {
            return new CustomPersistenceStore() as T;
        }

        return null;
    }

    public ICollection<T> GetAllInstances<T>() where T : class
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: That is pretty much exactly what I have. However, if I put a breakpoint on the `GetInstance` method, it never gets hit. This led me to believe that it wasn't the `IServiceLocator`, but rather something to do with the registration of it.

Comment: when you say your breakpoint is not hit, do you start the application with F5 or do you attach once the application started? Because it will only be hit on first request, once everything is initialized, the servicelocator is not used any longer. Do you see errors in the glimpse.log that might give you some indication?

Comment: I start with F5. Ah didn't realise you could toggle logging. I'll try this and then get back, thanks.